# MS SQL INSERT INTO trouble

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to insert new record in table.
The first column name ob_no is int, not null. So I need generate number which is maximum ob_no at the moment +1. How can I do it? Something Like (max(ob_no) + 1) but it doesn't work in SQL 2005. Thanks for any ideas.

```
INSERT INTO et_thanks_2014 (ob_no, c_name)
VALUES (???, 'Some Text')
```

Comment: Use an [`Identity` column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx). `CREATE TABLE et_thanks_2014 
(
 ob_no  int IDENTITY(1,1),
 c_name varchar (20)
);`

Comment: if you want to use `ob_no` as a key, you should make it the primary key in your table schema and set it up with auto incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use identities if you don't need values without lag:

```
INSERT INTO et_thanks_2014 (ob_no, c_name)
SELECT MAX(ob_no) + 1, 'Some Text'
FROM et_thanks_2014
```